# Keyboard does not appear in Android custom dialog

Tags: android

The keyboard does not appear in the custom dialog.
I tried various methods such as the following, but did not succeed.

```
passwdDialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
passwdDialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
edtTitle.requestFocus();
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(edtTitle, 0);
```

Is there a way to use the keyboard in the `EditText` of a custom dialog?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final PasswdDialog passwdDialog = new PasswdDialog(MainActivity.this);
        passwdDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        passwdDialog.show();

        Button btnConfirm = passwdDialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_confirm);
        Button btnCancel = passwdDialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
        final EditText edtTitle = passwdDialog.findViewById(R.id.edt_title);
    }
}

public class PasswdDialog extends Dialog
{
    private Context context;

    public PasswdDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_passwd);
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        EditText edtTitle = findViewById(R.id.edt_title);
    }
}
```

Is the layout wrong by any chance?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_warning">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="text1"
            android:textColor="#898989"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="#dcdcdc" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:text="text2"
            android:textColor="#747474"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/dialog_border">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:inputType="numberPassword"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_add"
                android:text="text3"
                android:textColor="#747474"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_confirm"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_add"
                android:text="text4"
                android:textColor="#747474"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show keyboard when open custom dialog, like this,

```
InputMethodManager ime = null;

ime = (InputMethodManager)Category_Edit.this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

ime.showSoftInputFromInputMethod(((EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.edt)).getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

try add below code in your editText xml file.

```
android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
```

**UPDATE : other way**
how about add lisener in dialog?

```
passwdDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

            @Override

            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {

                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)                                      mContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

                imm.showSoftInput(mFullPopUpEditBox, 0);

            }

        });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer
But it still doesn't work

Comment: Thanks not only on certain tablets, but on other devices
I think it’s a problem with the tablet. Thank you very much.